# Store jquery png http response on the server using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, httpresponse

I am using the restpack.io API to capture a screenshot of a website.
My jquery call returns a png file.
The output of the returned file in the console looke like this:

[image]

What I want to do: I want to store this http response on my server using php.
So I am posting that string to my php file - but I don't know how to handle this to store it.
I tried just putting this string into a new created png file, but it says it is a destroyed image.

How can I store this data in a new file on my server?

Thank you

edit:

I am creating the blog to make it accessable using $_FILES

```
let blob = new Blob([responseimage], {
type: "image/png"
});
fd.append('file', blob);
```

my serverside php looke like this:

```
$filepath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = "newfile.png";

$move_result = move_uploaded_file($filepath, $filename);
echo $move_result;
```

it is creating a png with a valid file size but i can not open it sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a string, it's binary data which has been encoded as a string because you're viewing it through the console. To send it to the server you can send a FormData object in an AJAX request, something like this:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', screenshotDataHere);

$.ajax({
  url: 'yourpage.php',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: data,
  success: function() {
    console.log('it worked!');
  }
});
```

Then in your PHP you can use `$_FILES['file']` to access the file data and save it wherever you require.

Comment: Thanks! this is working now. I had to add type: "POST" to the ajax. Thank you very much :)

Comment: To make it accessable with $_FILES I also had to add this: let blob = new Blob([responseimage], {
    type: "image/png"
}); it seems like the new file is created... but somehow it still is a destroyed image. I will add my PHP code in my first post

Comment: It's easier to use the PHP Lib... https://github.com/restpackio/restpack-php .. I didnt see this one before